# Erase from PostGIS line table using polygon table (like Erase in ArcGIS)

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis

I have two sets of data: a line table (roads) and a polygon table (localities)

Both sets are very large and contain thousands of geometries.

I need all the geometries or segments of geometries from the line table that lay outside the polygon table (in my case all the roads outside localities);

I tried something like:

```
create table roadsdifference as (select
 r.osm_id as osm_id, ST_Difference(r.geom,c.geom) geom
 from
roads r join localities c on ST_Crosses(c.geom,r.geom));
```

And it works if each roads joins only one locality. In case I have roads crossing two or more localities I get overlapping multigeometries, one for each locality (I know this is how a join works).

I also tried:

```
create table localitiesunion as select st_union(geom) geom from localities;

create table roadsdifference as (select
 r.osm_id as osm_id, ST_Difference(r.geom,c.geom) geom
 from
roads r join localitiesunion c on ST_Crosses(c.geom,r.geom));
```

But this option either takes forever or throws a topology error and crashes.

As I said, I have about 50k locality polygons and 5 mil. road linestrings.

Using the Erase function in ArcGIS does the job ok but I have to convert the tables to shapefiles, process them, convert them back etc. and this is a lot of time-consuming manual work. I would like an automated solution that I can include in a script (or an .sql file).

Any other ways or ideas on how to do this?